# Magento 2.4.2 How to hide duplicate pictures when the product color is switched

Tags: magento2.4.2

When the product is configurable, the default picture will be displayed repeatedly when switching colors. How to hide duplicate pictures when the product color is switched.

I have looked up many related issues, but the test still did not solve the problem.

Magento ver. 2.4.2

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code responsible for concatenating the images on product page is:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js#L1290

The value `this.options.gallerySwitchStrategy` can be changed to 'replace' to avoid configurable product images be merged to the simple product images.

In order to do that you can change the value of `gallery_switch_strategy` on the theme view.xml file:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/etc/view.xml#L266

You must change it on your theme:

```
app/design/frontend/Angelo/theme/etc/view.xml
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Viniciusbord9, There is no magento folder in the code folder. What should I do, when I use a third-party theme.

Comment: You can create a new theme that extends your third-party theme with  a custom etc/view.xml file. In my point of view it is the best option.

Comment: Could you please vote on my answer?

Comment: public_html/vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js
 
if (this.options.gallerySwitchStrategy === 'replace' && !isInitial) {
                    imagesToUpdate = imagesToUpdate.concat(initialImages);
                }

Change it, didn’t solve the problem.

Comment: Could you please update the question with your change?

Comment: Thank you very much.