# How to hide Magento 2.4.5 duplicate pictures when the product color is switched

Tags: product, color-swatches, magento2.4.5

I used to seek workarounds for magento 2.4.2 on the stackexchange that fixed this issue, but when I upgraded to magento 2.4.5, those workarounds were outdated because magento had a major upgrade.

How can I re-solve this problem, thank you all.

[Magento 2.4.2 How to hide duplicate pictures when the product color is switched](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/339442/magento-2-4-2-how-to-hide-duplicate-pictures-when-the-product-color-is-switched)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution still is the same, I've tested in magento 2.4.5:

Adding these lines of code to the theme view.xml file: < your theme dir>/etc/view.xml

```
<vars module="Magento_ConfigurableProduct">
    <var name="gallery_switch_strategy">replace</var>
</vars>
```

your theme view.xml will be looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <vars module="Magento_ConfigurableProduct">
        <var name="gallery_switch_strategy">replace</var>
    </vars>
</view>
```

You can read more here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.5/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/README.md#configurable-variables-through-the-theme-viewxml

Comment: Thank you, but still can't fix this problem.